# Problem dropping Hive table from pyspark script

Tags: json, hive, pyspark, hiveql, hive-serde

I have a table in hive created from many json files using hive-json-serde method, WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('dots.in.keys' = 'true'), as some keys there have a dot in, like `aaa.bbb`. I create external table and use backticks for these keys. Now I have a problem dropping this table from pyspark script, using `sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_name)`, I'm getting this error message:

```
An error occurred while calling o63.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot recognize hive type string: struct<associations:struct<aaa.bbb:array<string> ...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '.' expecting ':'(line 1, pos 33)
== SQL ==
struct<associations:struct<aaa.bbb:array<string>,...
---------------------------------^^^
```

In HUE i can drop this table without any problem. Am I doing it wrong, or may be there is better way to do it?

Comment: what is the value of `table_name`

Comment: @lugger1 try using `backticks` at start and end of table name

Comment: table_name value changes (as I need to process different tables), but generally it's in format 'test_event_aaa_bbb_ccc'. Backticks around table name don't help, the statement DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_event_aaa_bbb` gives the same error message. I think that for some reason it runs the table schema through parser, when I try to drop table in a script, but not when I do in in HUE, and that parser doesn't understand dots in key names.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not possible to work with Hive tables created with the hive-json-serde method, with dot in keys , using sqlContext.sql("...") from pyspark script, as I want. There is always the same error, if I want to drop such Hive table, or create it (haven't tried other things yet). So my workaround is to use python os.system() and execute required query through hive itself:

```
q='hive -e "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+ table_name+';"'
os.system(q)
```

It's more complicated with CREATE TABLE query, as we need to escape backticks with '\':

```
statement = "CREATE TABLE test111 (testA struct<\`aa.bb\`:string>) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION 's3a://bucket/test111';"
q='hive -e "'+ statement+'"'
```

It outputs some additional hive related info, but works!